# PHPspreadsheet show blank in browser tab

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I have used `https://github.com/PHPOffice/phpspreadsheet` this package to download
csv files in codeigniter

When I try to download it shows blank in browser tab and not showing download option

there are no errors

Tried with below code

```
   <?php
   if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   require 'vendor/autoload.php';
   use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
   use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

   class Reports extends Admin_Controller
   {
       public function download()
       {
             $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
             $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
             $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
             $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
             $writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
       }
   }
```

Can any anyone help on that please??.Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

class Reports extends Admin_Controller
{

  public function index()
  {
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $filename = 'hello world';

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');

    $writer->save('php://output');
  }
}
```

for csv just change the extesion .xlsx to .csv (case-sensitive)

Comment: Yes its working Pradeep, Does spreadsheet supports auto filter??

Comment: Yes, https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/autofilters/

Comment: could you please add setAutofilter() function to the above code to set auto filter.

Comment: AutoFilter range should always contain the heading row and one or more data rows (one data row is pretty meaningless,

Comment: let's assume we have multiple data,  then after which line I have put auto filter function??

Comment: for filtering many attribute have to set depends upon your requirement , giving ex, first u  have to select the range of column to apply  to check put this line of code : $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:E20'); after the $filename variable

Answer (score 1):

The download() function you have there is only for writing a new file. Not anything to do with downloading a file. However I managed to output a file using this code here. I outputted a csv file so I could check it more easily on my server but the premise is still the same with xlsx files.

```
public function writeFile() {
            $this->load->library('Spreadsheet'); 
            $output_file = getcwd() . "/test/hello_world.csv";
            $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
            $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow("1", "1", "Hello World!");
            $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Csv');
            $writer->save($output_file);
        }
```

I think part of your problem was not loading the library correctly using the CodeIgniter nomenclature. If you are trying to upload files I would reccomend using the upload library which comes with CodeIgniter. The documentation can be found here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

I would then use phpspreadsheet to edit it to your hearts content once it has been uploaded. Hope this helps.